# Doctrine 2 has me questioning the objective of collections, what kinds of methods can i have within collections, in general?

Tags: php, collections, doctrine-orm, oop

I was reading up on Doctrine 2, and I came across this post http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-dev/browse_thread/thread/3b21fcea5a408aae, in which a user wanted to extend the PersistantCollection class with a custom collection.  In it, another user responds,

> Collections are collections, they hold elements and provide means to
>   iterate over them or do other typical collection stuff (count, filter
>   items, add items, remove items, ...), always not caring about the
>   exact nature of the items (products, articles or whatever).
>   getTotalPrice or getTotalWeight on a collection are completely
>   misplaced and extending collection classes a similar bad idea in most
>   situations. It goes against many guidelines, single responsibility
>   principle being one of them. Put your business logic on your domain
>   objects/classes themselves, not on the collections. Collections are
>   just generic data containers.

My question is, if I wanted to do something with a collection of book objects, like sort them into categories and count the amount within each category, would it be incorrect to create a method within the collection class to do this?  Or should I make a static function within the entity to sort the collection?  I'm just not really sure where I would put this type of function....  Thanks in advance for taking time out of your day to read this post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

No, I would highly recommend against custom collections. The `Collection` interface provides a full public API to manipulate the collection in anyway, eliminating the need to subclass the collection.

In your `Category` you could write a method that sorts the `$books` collections. ...And possibly hook it into a PostLoad event. (Why did you suggest a `static` method?)